# Ios Paytm Oops error

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment-gateway, payment, paytm

I integrated paytm sdk. I am getting oops error. Its working fine in android app for same details as mid,orderid etc. But in ios app, it is getting oops error as in provided link.

[Paytm Payment gateway in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838980/paytm-payment-gateway-in-ios)

I searched in google, but i didnt find correct solution. Can anyone give me suggestions to solve this ?

So many posted exact oops error question in stackoverflow, but didnt get correct solution.

Comment: Can you the code that you have used if the issue is not resolved

Comment: Can you please share your request code? Its due because of  Checksumhash is not match.